# "Diff" for websites

Tags: webapp-rec

I seem to remember a while back seeing a website that would generate a 'diff' like report (highlight differences between versions) to show what had been changed on that site.

For example, if you noticed that there was a recent date on a company's privacy policy page, you could plug it in, and it'd show what had been removed or added.

Does anyone know of any sites or tools that exist to do this?

(I know about the Internet Archive, and I'm assuming that's what the site made use of to get their older version to compare to ... but I want it to highlight the changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these sites:

- http://www.changedetection.com/
- http://trackengine.com/servlets/com.nexlabs.trackengine.ui.Login
- http://watchthatpage.com/
- http://www.aignes.com/
- http://versionista.com/

This blog post has a review of some these sites and their features.

http://marshallk.com/a-review-of-web-site-change-detection-services

Comment: Thanks ... lots of interesting ones there ... but I'm actually trying to find one that'll look into the past (as I didn't think to start the monitoring *before* the page changed)

Comment: @Joe - I would have thought that Internet Archive would be your best bet for this. It would be hard to track page changes if you didn't know what were tracking :)

Comment: yes, but there was one that'd then go and generate a highlighted page of what had changed ... so you didn't have to read through a 20 screen 'terms of service' to figure out what paragraph had been inserted, or a few words changed, like you might get from ['view history' on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Internet_Archive&action=historysubmit&diff=391186315&oldid=389948335).  I'm guessing they made calls to the Internet Archive to get the documents to compare against.